# mocking fs.existsSync inside Express controller with Jest

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, jestjs, mocking

`**Problem:**

I want to mock `fs.existsSync()` only for the specific controller. Doing this the way below - applies mock on the method globally also outside the controller. This  causes the test to fail (as the `existsSync` function is used in various places of the app).

In my Express controller, I've got the following:

```
const fs = require('fs')

export default async (req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) => {
   ...
   if (!fs.existsSync(htmlTemplate)) {
      return next(new ServerError(500, ResponseMessages.ss_error_template_not_rendered))
   }
   ...
}
```

In my corresponding supertest test with Jest, I've got:

```
  const _fs = fs.existsSync
  const mockedExistSync = jest.fn().mockImplementation((file: any) => {
    return false
  })
  fs.existsSync = mockedExistSync
  await request(app.server)... // and so on...
  fs.existsSync = _fs // restore to the original
```

I don't do `jest.mock(...)` anywhere in the test. Just this.

Is there any better or valid way to resolve this?

Comment: ` = jest.fn()` is a terrible practice, reassignment destroys original implementation permanently. In your case a failed test will result in test cross-contamination because `fs.existsSync = _fs` fails to execute. Use jest.spyOn to mock methods and accessors, use reassignments in beforeEach for other properties to unconditionally restore original value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
import fs from 'fs';
const spy = jest.spyOn(fs, 'existsSync').mockImplementation();
```